# How to 'trust' self signed .dev certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using the following code to generate a certificate as we transition to using a purchased .dev domain for local development:

```
openssl req -x509 -out domain.dev.crt -keyout domain.dev.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -days 3650 \
  -subj '/C=UK/O=Vizibl/CN=*.domain.dev' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=*.domain.dev\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:*.domain.dev\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

The certificate is working fine on Mac OSX after adding it to Keychain Access but on ubuntu I am running into issues using any browser.

I have tried adding the certificate to my `ca-certificates` and have ensured it appears in my `certificates.crt`.

In chrome when accessing a localhost domain pointing to the URL such as microservice1.domain.dev I'm greeted with a `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`. I have also confirmed this does not work if I try to specify a specific subdomain rather than a root cert.

Comment: Create a local CA (certificate authority). It is not trivial, but doable.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openssl genrsa -out domain.dev.key 2048
openssl req -new -key domain.dev.key -out *.domain.dev.csr

openssl x509 -req -in *.domain.dev.csr -CA domainCA.crt -CAkey domainCA.key -CAcreateserial \
-out domain.dev.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile *.domain.dev.ext

sudo cp domain.dev.crt domainCA.crt  /usr/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificate
```

This process worked after I had generated a CA crt and key.

Comment: Much better to use `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, so you don't interfere with the package manager. `/usr/local` was [specially reserved for this purpose](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html).